# How can i include a JS in entry js and access it from other components

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

I want to be able to use a Socket.IO instance in my Vue components, i don't want to have to `import io from 'socket.io-client'` in every component file so i thought i should be able to import it in my "main.js" file and use it anywhere else.

So far, I've seen several answers but none of them seem to work

I've tried to include

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
...

var sock = io('localhost:3000')

export const globalStore = new Vue({
  data: {
    sock: sock
  }
})
```

In my main.js and call it like

```
import {globalStore} from '../main.js'

const SOCK = globalStore.sock
```

But i still get 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: sock is not defined at Object.login`

When i try to do

`SOCK.emit()`

I want to be able to include a JS file (not just socket.io) once, and call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind your sock to VueJS prototype:

```
// main.js file

import Vue from 'vue'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const sock = io('localhost:3000')

Vue.prototype.$sock = sock

new Vue({
    ...
})
```

You could then be able to access it in your components like this:

```
export default {
    created () {
        console.log(this.$sock)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for what i asked, but i discovered i need more than this. It works when i use it in components but if i want to use it in an an external JS file i can't access it. For example, i have "auth.js" which i include in my 'index.vue', i pass the login details to a 'auth.js' where the actual authentication is done.

How can i use this.$sock in the external JS.